# Unable to print hash table iterator in powershell when hashtable is created from file

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

I am trying to read a config file using PowerShell and then convert it to hashtable so that later I can retrieve the value by key.

Here is the code:

```
$installerConfigs = Get-Content $configFilePath | ConvertFrom-StringData
$installerConfigs
foreach ($h in $installerConfigs.GetEnumerator()) {
    Write-Host "$($h.Name): $($h.Value)"
}
```

While the content of the config file is

```
admin_username = 'administrator'
admin_password = '123456'
```

when I print the hashtable, it prints the value properly. But when I am iterating over it, it is unable to print anything.

Can someone point out what I am missing?

Just to mention, I have to use version 1.0 of PowerShell.

Comment: `$installerConfigs` is not a hashtable, but an array containing two separate hashtables. use `Get-Content $configFilePath -Raw` or `(Get-Content $configFilePath) -join [Environment]::NewLine`

Comment: Tried both way, it is printing nothing.

Comment: You still need to pipe it to `ConvertFrom-StringData`. What does `$installerConfigs.GetType()` show you?

Comment: I tried this way : $installerConfigs = Get-Content $configFilePath -Raw| ConvertFrom-StringData

Comment: PowerShell v1.0 doesn't support `Get-Content -Raw` (the parameter was introduced with v3). You need `Get-Content $configFilePath | Out-String`. And I think `ConvertFrom-StringData` was introduced with PowerShell v2.0, so you'd need to parse the data yourself (or upgrade).

Comment: yeah ..so I parsed the data to make a common hash table and then use that to access values.